# return canvas code line from function without eval

Tags: javascript, eval

it's my first Stack question so excuse my formatting.
I'm making a simple vector drawing tool.  [full CodePen code here](https://codepen.io/Michal_Kaleta/pen/NjaOEO?editors=0011)

So I made a DRAW object with method 'temp' with 'template' canvas drawing commands inside and want to input a variable code line between, which is returned from other methods of this object (add, sub...).

```
temp(operation){

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y);  
  eval(operation);
  ctx.strokeStyle="red";
  ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

Can somebody help me to avoid eval(), which, I read is bad and error prone.
Also every other suggestion  would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: You can take `ctx` as argument and perform operation

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as an argument to temp.

```
doSomething(options) {
  // some code to execute
}

temp(callback) {
  const options = {};

  callback(options);
}

temp(doSomething)
```

Comment: Thank for response. In tried it but didn't give result.  It occured I passed to 'temp' a function with arguments,like that:  'DRAW.temp( DRAW.add(v1,v2) )' and it didn't work,but when I passed only  'DRAW.add' and  in 'temp' I invoked 'operation(v1,v2)'  it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so the thing was that I passed to DRAW.temp an add function with arguments and it didn't work.
Now i pass only DRAW.add and arguments (v1,v2) are added inside temp method and its ok.

```
DRAW={
add(v1,v2){},
sub(v1,v2){},   /////operations

temp(operation){

  console.log(operation)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y);  
  operation(v1,v2);/////////////input operation
  ctx.strokeStyle="red";
  ctx.stroke();
 } 
 };
var draw =DRAW.temp;
var add =DRAW.add;

draw(add)
```